# How to run SEQUENCE setVal from Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

How can I execute PostgreSQL's [sequence manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-sequence.html), such as `setVal()` through Hibernate? For example:

```
SELECT setval('license_req_seq', (select max (id)+1 as maxVal from agents_requests))

org.hibernate.Session session = ...
session.createSQLQuery(command).executeUpdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain the setval procedure returned value then you should use the uniqueResult():

```
Long nextVal = (Long)session.createSQLQuery(command).uniqueResult();
```